# Spring Security configuration not allowing public access to specific endpoints

Tags: java, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, microservices

As the title states, I am facing issues allowing access to what should be publicly accessible endpoints in my microservices architecture. I am using Keycloak for role-based authentication, which works great, except when accessing public endpoints, I keep running into a `401 Unauthorized` error, despite using the `.permitAll()` method in my `SecurityFilterChain` Bean.

It is important to note that I am also using the Spring Clouds API gateway to route incoming requests to the load-balanced microservice.

The code and configuration classes are pasted below, but this is what I have been trying for the last few days to solve the issue.

1. I initially implemented the authentication at the API gateway level. However, no matter what I tried, I kept getting the 401 status when accessing the endpoints from my microservice, which led to solution attempt 2.
2. I implemented the authentication at the microservice level instead, and the role-based authentication worked, but accessing the public endpoints was still an issue.
3. I tried disabling CSRF in my microservice `SecurityFilterChain` Bean, but it also didn't change anything.
4. At the moment, I completely removed the public endpoints from the `SecurityFilterChain` Bean in my microservice. Instead, I added the public endpoint at the API gateway level in the `SecurityWebFilterChain` Bean, which also did not work.
5. As a last resort, I added the `PermitAll` annotation from the `javax.annotation.security` package to my endpoints in my `PublicUserController` (the controller class for all publically available endpoints) which did not work.

Other than tutorials, this is the first time I am implementing something like this on my own so it is still fairly new and I am not sure where to go from here. Any guidance towards the right direction on the issue would be greatly appreciated. I'm happy to clarify anything or add any additional code if needed. Any help/guidance is greatly appreciated.

## User Service

##### SecurityConfiguration

**Note:** the path I am trying to make public is `/public/users/**`. It should accept HttpMethod.PUT, HttpMethod.DELETE, and HttpMethod.POST.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final AuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfiguration(AuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter) {
        this.authenticationConverter = authenticationConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securedSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request
                        .requestMatchers("/public/users/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/admins/users/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers("/subscribers/users/**").hasRole("SUBSCRIBER")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

## Api Gateway

##### UserServiceRouteConfiguration

```
@Configuration
public class UserServiceRouteConfiguration {

    private final String API_VERSION = "v0.1-dev";

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator userServiceRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route("user-service", route -> route
                        .path("/user-service/" + API_VERSION + "/subscribers/users/**")
                        .and().method(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.PUT, HttpMethod.POST, HttpMethod.DELETE)
                        .uri("lb://user-service"))
                .route("user-service", route -> route
                        .path("/user-service/" + API_VERSION + "/admins/users/**")
                        .and().method(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.PUT, HttpMethod.POST, HttpMethod.DELETE)
                        .uri("lb://user-service"))
                .route("user-service", route -> route
                        .path("/user-service/" + API_VERSION + "/public/users/**")
                        .and().method(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.PUT, HttpMethod.POST, HttpMethod.DELETE)
                        .uri("lb://user-service"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

##### SecurityConfiguration

**Note:** this is is where I first started implementing the role-based auth, but wasn't working as mentioned above.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity security) {
        return security.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeExchange(exchange -> exchange
                        .pathMatchers("/eureka/**").permitAll()
                        .anyExchange().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(ServerHttpSecurity.OAuth2ResourceServerSpec::jwt)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.permitAll()` means permit any role, but you still put `authenticated()` - which means that the user has to be authenticated via Keycloak (in your case) to access.

What you probably want instead is something along these lines (I haven't tested but hopefully shows the idea - that you need a separate block without `authenticated()`:

```
http.authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request
                        .requestMatchers("/admins/users/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers("/subscribers/users/**").hasRole("SUBSCRIBER")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
.and()
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
                       .requestMatchers("/public/users/**").permitAll()
.and()
        .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter);
```

Comment: I'll give this a try thank you. Should this be done at the api-gateway level or the microservice level?

Comment: That didn't work either sadly. I am not entirely sure where to go from here. I was thinking of moving everything security related into the api-gateway, but I still want to be able to test that the endpoints are secured in the microservice.

Comment: Try to change the order / check if you have other blocks that may be hijacking the global paths, i.e. `/**` and also that the path locations are actually correct. We have a similar configuration working in some of our projects - so I would suggest trying to do just a hello world project on that first - generally, I know this is working from past experience (although could be some other config interfering here). We are also trying to avoid usage of API Gateways where possible - I can probably find a reference if you're interested.

Comment: I’ll try debugging more and see if there is any other configuration or paths interfering. In regards to the reference, I’d love to take a look at it. Based on simple Google searches, implementing the authentication and authorization at the API Gateway level or the microservice level seems to be subjective.

Comment: This is the talk on the subject that is very good I believe - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rXi5CLjIQ9k

Comment: I posted a comment with the solution. Appreciate the help — I enjoyed the video as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved the issue, thanks to the help from @taleodor.  It wasn’t related to anything interfering with the requests — simply poor design on my end.

I simply had to modify the security configuration in my API Gateway to pwrmit all requests to my micro-service like below:

```
   @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity security) {
        security.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeExchange(exchange -> exchange
                        .pathMatchers("/eureka/**").permitAll()
                        .pathMatchers("/user-service/v0.1-dev/**").permitAll()
                        .anyExchange().authenticated());

        return security.build();
    }
```

Then in the micro-service, the configuration somewhat stayed the same:

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securedSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request
                        .requestMatchers("/public/users/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/auth/admins/users/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers("/auth/subscribers/users/**").hasRole("SUBSCRIBER")
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated());

        http.oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

This [article](https://www.solutelabs.com/blog/authentication-and-authorization-in-microservices#:%7E:text=An%20API%20gateway%20should%20be,microservices%20specific%20to%20the%20application) also helped me solve the issue. This can be a subjective topic, but to summarize it, authentication checks should be done at the API Gateway level and the authorization checks should be done at the micro-service level.